# Comparing two dates in excel returns a wrong result

Tags: excel-2016

I am comparing two dates and if the date 1 is greater than the date 2, the License status must be shown as "Valid license" if not the "Expired license" is shown. 
but I always got "Expired license" in all case.

[image]

I am using this formula in Excel 2016:

```
IF([@[Date 1]]>=$BB$2;"Valid license";"Expired license")
```

Comment: Is column `Date 1` formatted as DateTime, or as Text?

Comment: It's formatted as DateTime

Answer (score 0):

The formula is correct.

'Date 1' column must be a date and also $bb$2

In Excel the date cells are numbers. You can check with =ISNUMBER(BB2) in any cell and the result must be TRUE. Also with 'Date 1'

Comment: The cells format is well set to "date" but as a result I got "False" for date 1 and date 2 also... I don't know why..

Comment: I think that date 1 are not dates. Excel recognices them as text. Try this:

1. Disable all filters
2. In an empty cell capture 1 (number one). For example in Z1
3. Select Z1 press Control-C  (copy)
4. Select Date 1 range
5. Select Special Paste, Multiplicate

This must convert all text to number (dates). You can delete Z1

Answer (score 0):

I was comparing the dates in two columns to see if they were the same or different `=IF(D2=N2,"same","different")` and it was returning incorrect results.

The check suggested by Salvador Rodriguez Segura was the key to my problem. One column was not ***formatted as date***, even though if I selected a cell and checked format, it showed as date. The `=ISNUMBER` function exposed the problem.

I selected the column and used ***Data/Text to Columns*** to correct the formatting. Then my simple formula worked.